# Swift Whole Module Optimization Off causes double compiles

Tags: swift, xcode

One of the projects I'm working on has this incredibly mysterious characteristic. When `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION` is set to `YES`, the application takes about 150 seconds to compile from a clean state. However when it's set to `NO`, the same application takes 11 minutes to compile after a clean. Not only that but several build steps happen multiple times, such as Swift compile sources getting run twice and precompiling the bridging header (which occurs 3 times). When optimization is turned on, these issues completely disappear and I was able to verify by digging through xcodebuild logs that compilation is only happening once.

What would cause behavior like this? Something about our project is configured in such a way that without optimization turned on, things go crazy. And why does turning on Swift whole module optimization fix it?

EDIT:

This is using swift 4.0.3 and Xcode 9.2

Comment: Impossible to answer in detail, but think about what whole module optimization does: it allows the compiler to consider multiple files simultaneously.

Comment: By the way I suggest you try Xcode 9.3 and the new build system.

Comment: Yeah obviously it's impossible to give a concrete answer here without looking at the project itself which is closed source so thats a no-go.

Comment: It has to be something specific about our project and I'm trying to eliminate potential causes. I might dig into the compiler documentation and see whats going on.

Comment: ok but do try 9.3 first because speeding up compilation is supposed to be a major feature